# Como posso sobrepor gráficos com datas diferentes pelo Matplotlib?

Tags: python, matplotlib, matemática

Como posso sobrepor três gráficos com datas diferentes em um mesmo gráfico? O código acaba gerando inícios diferentes, mas precisava plotar isso à partir de um mesmo início para a composição de um trabalho [inserir a descrição da imagem aqui](https://i.stack.imgur.com/hiplK.png).

```
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd
import pandas_datareader.data as wb
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import yfinance as yf

yf.pdr_override()
%matplotlib inline

CRFB3 = yf.download('CRFB3.SA', start = '2017-07-20', end = '2019-07-20')['Adj Close']
MGLU3 = yf.download('MGLU3.SA', start = '2011-05-02', end = '2013-05-02')['Adj Close']
ASAI3 = yf.download('ASAI3.SA', start = '2021-03-01', end = '2023-03-01')['Adj Close']

norm_CRFB3 = CRFB3/CRFB3.iloc[0]*100
norm_MGLU3 = MGLU3/MGLU3.iloc[0]*100
norm_ASAI3 = ASAI3/ASAI3.iloc[0]*100

plt.plot(norm_CRFB3, linestyle='-', marker='o', color = 'blue', markersize = 2)
plt.plot(norm_MGLU3, linestyle='-', marker='o', color = 'red', markersize = 2)
plt.plot(norm_ASAI3, linestyle='-', marker='o', color = 'green', markersize = 2)

plt.ylabel('Retorno', fontsize=10)
plt.xlabel('Período', fontsize=10)

axes = plt.gca()
axes.yaxis.grid(color='black', alpha=0.5, linestyle='--', linewidth=1)

plt.title('Desempenho Varejo - Período Pós-IPO')
plt.figure(figsize=(15, 8))
plt.show()
```

Answer (score 0):

Visto que nos 3 casos se trata de um período de 2 anos podemos contar o número de dias desde a data inicial de cada um.

```
start1 = pd.to_datetime('2017-07-20')
start2 = pd.to_datetime('2011-05-02')
start3 = pd.to_datetime('2021-03-01')
a = norm_CRFB3
b = norm_MGLU3
c = norm_ASAI3
a.index = (pd.to_datetime(a.index) - start1).days
b.index = (pd.to_datetime(b.index) - start2).days
c.index = (pd.to_datetime(c.index) - start3).days

plt.plot(a, linestyle='-', marker='o', color = 'blue', markersize = 2)
plt.plot(b, linestyle='-', marker='o', color = 'red', markersize = 2)
plt.plot(c, linestyle='-', marker='o', color = 'green', markersize = 2)
```

[image: Overlap Graphs]